# deploy application on couchdb

Tags: couchdb, couchapp

I would like to deploy my application on couchdb. Have few queries regarding the same.

1) Is couchapp the only way to install applications on couchdb?

2) Can we deploy only javascript/HTML in couchdb?

I found that all the files except the files in web-inf from my application war can be pushed into couchdb. What will happen to the files in web-inf?

Thanks

Jo

Answer (score 3):

1/ couchapp is just a tool that pushes a design document with views, show, list functions, and so on. The default generated couchapp contains evently code, as it is the most common way to write couchapps. Other tools exist:

- Sammy on Couch App: http://github.com/quirkey/soca
- Couchapp Package manager: http://github.com/caolan/cpm

2/ You can deploy any kind of attachment, and really anything that is usually in a design document. Check couchapp.org for more informations on couchapp.

3/ A WAR file is Java code, this won't get you anywhere with CouchDB.

Comment: All these tools are simply using the [CouchDB HTTP API](http://www.couchbase.org/sites/default/files/uploads/all/documentation/couchbase-api.html). CouchDB doesn't put any limits on the Content-Type of the documents being added as a document attachment. Two other tools of note are [Reupholster](http://reupholster.iriscouch.com/reupholster/_design/app/index.html) and [node.couchapp.js](https://github.com/mikeal/node.couchapp.js).